# Java: Finding the value in an array list that is closest to a particular negative number

Tags: java, compare

My question is how I can write a method that takes an ArrayList of Doubles as a parameter and returning the Double in the array list that is closest to -3.75.

I got the code down for the positive number 3.42, but I'm stuck as to modifying it to suit -3.75

```
public static double question3(ArrayList<Double> input) {

    double myNum = 3.42.;
    double dist = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double closest = 0.0;

    for (Double s : input) {
        if (Math.abs(Math.abs(s) - myNum) < dist) {
            dist = Math.abs(Math.abs(s) - myNum);
            closest = s;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(closest);
    return closest;
}
```

Any help? Or better way to go about performing this task?

Comment: Why do you have any magic numbers inside your code in the first place? If you clean up this mess, you automatically obtain a solution that works for any number.

Comment: Why do you do `Math.abs(s)`? I think if your remove `Math.abs` the code should work.

Comment: ...and why do you compute the candidate-distance twice, if `dist` is reassigned? Furthermore, this method obviously shouldn't print anything.

Comment: You might want to add your number to the array sort it and then use the vakue next to it...

Comment: @NielsNet not `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you got the absolute value of `s`:

```
if (Math.abs(Math.abs(s) - myNum) < dist) {
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This means that every negative number in the array will be treated as if it were a positive number. This is why your method cannot find the correct closest number to -3.75.

Just remove the `abs` call:

```
if (Math.abs(s - myNum) < dist) {
```

Alternatively, use the Stream API like this:

```
return input.stream()
    // compares the value of Math.abs(x - myNum), where x is each element of input
    .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(x -> Math.abs(x - myNum)))
    // returns positive infinity if there is nothing in "input"
    .orElse(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

But since this looks like homework, I doubt a Stream API approach will be accepted...

Answer (score 0):

If it's not your explicit goal to reinvent the wheel, you can use `stream`'s `min` with a custom comparator:

```
public double findClosestTo(ArrayList<Double> arr, double value) {
  return arr.stream().min(
    Comparator.<Double>comparingDouble(x -> Math.abs(x - value))
  ).get();
}
```

The `get` part (that comes from `Optional`) will throw an error if the array is empty.